# Laravel Ajax not working

Tags: ajax, laravel

I try to update a price attribute with ajax but it's not working, so i tested if i get something from the reponse but still nothing

here my controller :

```
public function attributePrice(Request $request){


        if ($request->has('size')) {

            return response()->json(['price'=>'ok']);


        }else {



        }
    }
```

Here my script fonction

```
 <script>
        $('#size').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url : 'size-price',
                dataType: "json",
                data : {
                    size : document.getElementById('size').value
                },

                success:function(data){

                    $('#price').html(data.price);



                }


            });
        });
    </script>
```

And finally here is the place that i want to update the price at id=price

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="text-normal">{{$product->name}}</h2><span class="h2 d-block">
                <!--<del class="text-muted text-normal">$68.00</del>&nbsp; $47.60</span>-->
                    <span class="text-muted text-normal" id="price">{{$product->price}} €</span>
                    <div class="padding-top-1x"></div>
                <!--description -->
                <p>
                   {{$product->description}}
                </p>


//Specefic Price
Route::post('/size-price' , 'ProductController@attributePrice');
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the network tab? like a 422 response?

Comment: i get a reponse 200 and it's display me the webpage in the preview tab

Comment: Please show your routes

Comment: Route::get('/size-price' , 'ProductController@attributePrice');

Comment: what is this line for? `//Specefic Price
Route::post('/size-price' , 'ProductController@attributePrice');` and should the app go back and forth with backend .. or is it a one time request?

Comment: sorry it's a get ! i copy paste wrong, i was doing some text to call the route as post

Comment: is it a one time request per page load?

Comment: yes exactly !!!

Comment: you can make it with input hidden, I'm passing the answer below because the comments is not code friendly

Comment: Your code should work if is pointing to the right url, I tested it already. What do you see on the preview response?

Comment: i see my page nothing change

Comment: could you share with me the test code you made who work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through you code twice now, it has no issues!

you have a dedicated function/controller for Ajax process.

calling that **attributePrice** which should return everything correctly.

and there is a *get* route **size-price** as you corrected in the comments

I'm not sure how you are showing the #size on your blade, but change event seems sufficient enough.

the only remaining 2 pieces that you didn't show in your questions are the value that you are passing,

console.log() the following code, to check if it is returning the correct data.

```
document.getElementById('size').value
```

Also, check the network tab in chrome dev tools and press on XHR, you should see there your ajax requests, you will find your link, followed by a question mark and then size=your-selected-value like this

```
size-price?size=your-selected-value
```

and BTW, that should show a status, which should be a clue on what is happening.

### Working Code

```
HTML
    <div class="panel-body">
        <select id="read-data">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
              </select>
              <input type="text" value="">
</div>
```

AJAX

```
$('#read-data').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : 'test/read-data',
            dataType: "json",
            data : {
                size : $("#read-data").attr("value")
            },

            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $("input").attr("value", data.price);
            }
        });
    });
```

Route

```
Route::get('test/read-data','AjaxController@readData');
```

Controller

```
   public function readData(Request $request){
if ($request->has('size')) {
    return response()->json(['price' => $request->size]);
} else{
    return 'no data!';
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer where i can use it with my ajax code ?

Comment: yes it's really nice but i need to find a price depending on a size wish is on my database. could i still do it ?

Comment: i need to get the price after change to a controller who get the new value, it"s possible with this way?

Comment: if it were for me, I would do it as eager-loading 'to keep things quick' from the backend, again if it is only 1 product per page, so I would pass all the sizes from the controller and then swap them the front view, however if you are planning to do this per multiple products or other data than price, you need ajax , that is way I asked before answering is it a one time request per load.

Comment: which answer do you prefer? eager loading or ajax? can you elaborate more about what you are going to achieve?

Comment: yes i need ajax .. for this thing but i gave a nice trick i will use it in other cases

Comment: ajax sir, i would like to put the ajax reponse to my span attribute

Comment: I would like to make an ajax function who take the size then i send it to my ProductController then i’m looking with a query the price who correspond with the size of this particular product then i display the result to the span. And with an hidden input i take the reponse value in order to call it back with another controller ( CartController )

Comment: @Mathieu I updated the answer, and will update it again with the code I tested with.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the csrf token with ajax request Please check the below code :

```
$('#country').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:"{{ url('getStates')}}",
       data: {
            country: $(this).val(),
            '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        },
       success : function(data){
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            var option = '<option value="">--- state ---</option>';
            for(var i in data){
                option += '<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>';
            }
            $("#state").html(option);
       }
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks for your nice exemple, could i do it also with a GET method ?

Comment: many thanks for your detailled exemple @HamzaMohamed i will test your code and see you i get something , many thanks again i let you know